# HTML: link that goes to same page where the link is, how to keep the view of the page?

Tags: html, hyperlink

when you click on a link that goes to same page where the link is, how to keep the view of the page?

By default it goes to the **top** of the same page.

Regards

Javier

Answer (score 1):

Can you be more specific? What do you mean with "view of the page"?

Here is a general description of anchors:

If you have a link `<a href="#someTarget">Link</a>` then you need an element on the same page with `id="someTarget"`. When you then click on the link, that element will be scrolled to the top of the element.

EDIT:
Ahm, you are talking about a JavaScript link. In that case you need to have the Javascript retur `false` so that the default action (namely following the link) is ignored:

```
<a href="#" ... onClick="myJqueryFunction(); return false;">
```

Comment: "view of the page": I mean the vertical position of the page.

Comment: Can you describe your problem in more detail?

Comment: I have a table (it just shows the head) far from the top of the page. When i click on the head of the table it shows the body of the table, but the view changes to show the top of the page, so i have to go down to see the table again...

Comment: And the link is like this <a href="#" ... onClick="myJqueryFunction()>

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to add `#` at the end of the `href` attribute on the links pointing to the current page, either manually or via javascript. I don't think it's a nice way to do it, though...

If you really need this, you could also "disable" the navigation for links pointing to the current page, so that clicking on a link to the current page would have no action...

Something like that should work in jQuery :

```
$('a.current').click(function(event){
    //cancel default click action
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

assuming that the links pointing to the current page have the CSS class `current`